# 'sudo nginx' vs 'sudo service nginx start'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn, rbenv

I have the following setup:

`NGINX 1.6.2, Rails 4, Unicorn, Capistrano 3.1`

I am getting the following errors in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2015/01/03 22:27:13 [crit] 49826#0: *77 stat() "/home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/current/public//index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:13 [crit] 49826#0: *77 stat() "/home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/current/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:13 [crit] 49826#0: *77 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock:/", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:13 [crit] 49826#0: *77 stat() "/home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/current/public/500.html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock/", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:13 [crit] 49826#0: *77 stat() "/home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/current/public/500.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock/", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:13 [crit] 49826#0: *77 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock:/500.html", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:14 [crit] 49826#0: *77 stat() "/home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/current/public/favicon.ico/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:14 [crit] 49826#0: *77 stat() "/home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/current/public/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:14 [crit] 49826#0: *77 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:14 [crit] 49826#0: *77 stat() "/home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/current/public/500.html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock/favicon.ico", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:14 [crit] 49826#0: *77 stat() "/home/mjp/apps/mjp-portal_staging/current/public/500.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock/favicon.ico", host: "185.48.117.98"
2015/01/03 22:27:14 [crit] 49826#0: *77 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 182.178.190.121, server: 185.48.117.98, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.mjp-portal_staging.sock:/500.html", host: "185.48.117.98"
```

I've tried running `nginx` as `root`, `mjp` and `nginx` as user but i get these same errors.

Even nginx doesn't create a server from `sites-enabled/symlink-to-deploy-root-shared-config-nginx.conf`although it does include it in `nginx -t` test.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Actually it wasn't a permissions error of the directories.

I stopped the nginx service and then started it as `sudo nginx` through which i was able to run the app with everything working. But when i tried to run it as a service by `sudo service nginx start` it gave the above errors for permission denied for the root dir & the socket.

I posted this same question on server fault and was lucky enough to get an answer.

Here is the [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/656299/nginx-permissions-sudo-nginx-vs-sudo-service-nginx-start/656371?noredirect=1#comment798785_656371):

> This is an selinux problem.
>
> When you run sudo nginx it starts nginx as `unconfined_t`, when you run
>   `sudo service nginx start` it starts `nginx` as `httpd_t`.
>
> By initially starting with just sudo it creates a bunch of files and
>   initializes its state as unconfined_t. For example the pid file will
>   be the wrong context. Thus when using service nginx stop to terminate
>   it there is insufficient privileges for httpd_t to read files written
>   by the `unconfined_t`.
>
> You should really always start using service which will avoid this
>   problem. To correct it you will need to relabel stateful files that
>   exist in the filesystem, for example running `restorecon
>   /var/run/nginx.pid` will correct the incorrect label set on that pid
>   file.
>
> I am not sure if there are any more files that get written out when
>   the service is created which will also need correcting. You can get a
>   list of which files that these might be doing `ausearch -ts recent -m
>   avc`.